# How to correct modificat of state arrays in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, setstate

I tried to find the current modification of setting a new element into an array in react.js with 'setState'.
Everything I tried just didn't add the new element to the array, it just replaced it with a new element.

```
const [unplannedCards, setUnplannedCards] = useState([card]);
setUnplannedCards([{...unplannedCards}, { ...card }]);
```

I also tried some other similar modifications but nothing helped.

can someone see where I got wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new `card` in your array this way:

```js
const [unplannedCards, setUnplannedCards] = useState([card]);
setUnplannedCards([...unplannedCards, card]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way which is the fastest

```
setUnplannedCards(unplannnedCards.concat(card))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it seem to be logical, but still doesn't work for me –